# Lost Pilot logbooks/flight time records

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

I hold an ATP certificate Multi-engine land, commercial privileges single engine land. It was issued in 1973 just prior to leaving the Army.  As I understand it, the facility that held the Army flight records experienced a fire some years ago and the records were lost. Now, I've also lost my log books and the only thing I have to show I can fly is my ATP.

I have approximately 3,100 hours total time. What do I do?

Comment: You can use the times from the last 8710 as proof of those hours.  The examiner is required to validate those hours before signing the application.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://drs.faa.gov/browse/excelExternalWindow/DRSDOCID170645427920230104182548.0001?modalOpened=true) is a link to the FAA Inspector's guidance with respect to "lost Logbooks."

**See paragraph 5-172 LOST LOGBOOKS OR FLIGHT RECORDS**

Paragraph 5-172 B. provides an address for you to write to in order obtain copies of your FAA files.  The FAA Forms 8710-1, "Airman Certificate and/or Rating Application," that you completed prior to taking flight checks for your various certificates will contain much of the (then) current flight time information from your logbook (PIC time, night, cross-country, instrument, etc.).

So, depending on what it is that you are trying to recreate (total flight time, proof of the existence of a certificate, etc.) you  may find some useful information from the guidance linked above.

Also, here is a link to the [Airmen Inquiry Search Page](https://amsrvs.registry.faa.gov/airmeninquiry/) which will show you what information, with respect to certificates, is in the FAA's database.