Lost logbook want to fly again
I took flying lessons in the 1980’s and logged about 50 hours including solos but never got a ppl.  I want to start flying again but after several moves can’t find my pilot logbook.  Do I have any options other than starting over from scratch?

Do any of the following questions provide the information that you're looking for: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/767/7532 or https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45924/7532 or  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/99631/7532

@RalphJ's links are excellent. In particular, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/45926/20394 gives some ideas for how to move forward if you wish to reconstruct some (but certainly not all) of your logbook.

A student pilot who hasn't flown in 40 years is starting over from scratch.
Think about what's in that logbook.  Close to zero PIC time.  A handful of expired endorsements.  No current experience.  It has trivial value if you can find it.

Voting down because the pithy "trivial value" claim is simply not true. If the (student) pilot in question already satisfied cross country, certain ground maneuvers, etc... then the logbook could be worth literally thousands of dollars in savings. It depends completely on what was in it and where this pilot is.

@KennSebesta  It's okay to disagree.  As an instructor, I would not credit any of it.  It's the student pilot who brings the experience, not the 40-year-old maneuver logs.

Agreed to disagree. I would be open to crediting all of it on my CFI ticket, pursuant to seeing the pilot's actual (retained) skillset. If this pilot is a flying spouse, and has thousands of hours in the right seat navigating IFR, then I don't need to sit through another cross-country just to satisfy a missing signature. That's very different from someone who had only just barely soloed and hasn't been in the front seat of a car/plane/boat in 40 years. IMO, declaring it has "trivial value" is a decision to be left to Publicola's CFI, and not our random voices on the internet.
